# VC++ calling a Paint event into a button event

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

I'm making a Windows form in VC++ and I've found tons of material talking about how to call Paint events into other functions or events, however those tend to be in C# and that doesn't seem to work for me or they don't explain the actual syntax of the code for me to understand. I'm still learning the more detailed aspects of programming so just telling me to use Validate() doesn't do me much good.

```
private: System::Void Stand_wheel_Paint(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e)
```

I have my Paint event. That has if statements that read if certain criteria are met to change the points that are used in the painting.

```
private: System::Void button3_Click_1(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
```

And my button to click that I want to trigger the painting. I have tried using the Stand_wheel_Paint name and it is fraught with errors. I've tried almost everything to my knowledge to get it under the event in the button and I just can't. I also know that I have to 'erase' the old paint and redo the current work but from what I have found tends to almost get me there but is from C#. I would love any help that someone could offer.

```
 using ( // <- I get an error on this parantheses
 var g = Graphics.FromImage(Stand_wheel.Image))
                 {
                     e->Graphics->DrawLines(pen, points);
                     Stand_wheel.Refresh();
                 }
```

This looks close to a solution but still has errors.

Comment: You might consider abandoning the c++-cli for the task and explore other options / languages.

Comment: I honestly would move to c# but the only thing stopping me is I just started a class to learn it so I am hesitant.

Answer (score 0):

The `using` block exists only in C#, a necessity because it doesn't have deterministic destruction.  C++/CLI, like standard C++, does.  If you declare a variable of a `ref class` type, rather than a tracking handle, its `Dispose` method will be automatically called when the variable goes out of scope.

No `using` needed, and the C++/CLI approach is much more powerful than the C# one.  For example, C++/CLI deterministic destruction works with class member data as easily as locals.